# WebAPI : How to add the Account / Authentication logic to a self hosted WebAPI service

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin, self-hosting

I just came across a great reference example of using authenticated WebAPI with AngularJS:

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/742532/Using-Web-API-Individual-User-Account-plus-CORS-En?msg=4841205#xx4841205xx
```

An ideal solution for me would be to have such WebAPI service self hosted instead of running it as a Web application.
I just do not know where to place all of the authentication / authorization logic within a self hosted (OWIN / Topshelf) solution.
For example, in the Web app, we have these two files:  Startup.Auth, and ApplicationOAuthProvider:

Startup.Auth:

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        static Startup()
        {
            PublicClientId = "self";

            UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>());

            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };
        }

        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

        public static Func<UserManager<IdentityUser>> UserManagerFactory { get; set; }

        public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
        }
    }
```

ApplicationOAuthProvider:

```
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        private readonly string _publicClientId;
        private readonly Func<UserManager<IdentityUser>> _userManagerFactory;

        public ApplicationOAuthProvider(string publicClientId, Func<UserManager<IdentityUser>> userManagerFactory)
        {
            if (publicClientId == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("publicClientId");
            }

            if (userManagerFactory == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("userManagerFactory");
            }

            _publicClientId = publicClientId;
            _userManagerFactory = userManagerFactory;
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            // Add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header as Enabling the Web API CORS will not enable it for this provider request.
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

            using (UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager = _userManagerFactory())
            {
                IdentityUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                    return;
                }

                ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                    context.Options.AuthenticationType);
                ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
                AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
                context.Validated(ticket);
                context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
            }
        }

        public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
            {
                context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            // Resource owner password credentials does not provide a client ID.
            if (context.ClientId == null)
            {
                context.Validated();
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
        {
            if (context.ClientId == _publicClientId)
            {
                Uri expectedRootUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri, "/");

                if (expectedRootUri.AbsoluteUri == context.RedirectUri)
                {
                    context.Validated();
                }
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName)
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "userName", userName }
            };
            return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
        }
    }
```

I'm looking for a way to integrate these into my OWIN self hosted app, and have these authentication features. start upon application startup, and function as they do in the Web app version.